# Null Space of Large Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I am working on a project that requires me to compute the null space of fairly large sparse matrices (2400 x 2400) multiple times. So far I have been using the scipy library to do so (does not take in account that matrix is sparse), although I am sure there must be a faster way. Looking around I found lots of publications on different algorithms to do so, but I was hoping to take an easier route and use premade modules. Is there any python/C/C++/fortran/matlab/etc... library that could help me in this?

I tried looking for such modules, but I could only find scipy.sparse, but it unfortunately does not contain a function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Look in scipy.sparse.linalg there seems to be everything you need to find the null space.

For instance:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve

Comment: unfortunately I did try using spsolve, but where scipy.linalg.nullspace finds a kernel, spsolve seems to only return the trivial vector (0,0,0,...,0).

Comment: ah ok, yes maybe the solution wouldn't be useful if it finds only 0.
Then I would suggest to get the list of eigenvectors and eigenvalues from scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs - if my linear algebra notions are not too rusty the eigenvectors for eigenvalue 0 should span the null space...

Comment: I did not think of that, I will keep you updated

Comment: So, using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs one can specify which eigenvalue to look for. Doing so, the function returns the vectors with the closest eigenvalues, although these vectors are not close enough to the vector that I need (i.e. the vector I find by instead using scipy.null_space)

Comment: if you are getting different vectors it does not necessarily mean you have a problem - the critical question is if the vectors from scipy.null_space lies in the linear space spanned by the eigenvectors with eigenvalue 0

Comment: That subsaspace really should be 1dimensional, not only beacause I expect it to be so, but also because thats what scipy.null_space finds.